# How to remove and execute functions on items one-by-one in VB.net listbox

Tags: vb.net, button, listbox, access-control

So I have a VB.net function that looks like this:

```
Private Sub FlatButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton2.Click
    Dim fs As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(FlatListBox1.SelectedItem)
    fs.RemoveAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Deny))
    File.SetAccessControl(FlatListBox1.SelectedItem, fs)
    FlatListBox1.ClearSelected()
End Sub
```

I know how to reverse this operation in one individual item, but I have no idea how to do it on every single item on the listbox. I want to do this as I press a button on the exit form. How would I go about this? I've tried a For Each loop but it didn't work, at least not the way I did it.

Comment: Perhaps if you show the foreach loop tried we could point you where is the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop thru all items to remove the access rule it would be like this.

```
Private Sub RemoveAccessRule(item As String)
  Try
    Dim fs As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(item)
    fs.RemoveAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Deny))
    File.SetAccessControl(item, fs)
  Catch
  End Try
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
For Each item As String In FlatListBox1.Items
   RemoveAccessRule(item)
Next
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work, it doesn't throw any errors but after I press the exit button the .exe file that was selected is still not accessible. Here's the code of the exit form: http://pastebin.com/9B5n3bEM

Comment: I get this in the debug output: A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: You might need add the folder path to that file name.

Comment: It has the full path, I think it might be something to do with the application not having the rights to access that exe

Comment: Maybe, try running your app as admin or right click on the VS exe and run VS with this solution as admin for debugging.

Comment: It is an admin app, it edits the hosts file as another feature so it is all in admin

Comment: It must be something to do with using item As String, something to do with selecting the listbox item, because that exact same remove access rule code works with flatlistbox1.selecteditem in the form of the listbox

Comment: I can run a for each just like that, how do you add the file names?

Comment: I don't see where you are adding the file names to the listbox

Comment: Dim sFileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim fs As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(sFileName)
        fs.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Deny))
        File.SetAccessControl(sFileName, fs)
        FlatListBox1.AddItem(sFileName)

Comment: And specifically FlatListbox1.AddItem(sFileName)